# System depends heavily on emails - use gmail?

Tags: email, bulk-email, gmail

I am creating a system where it depends heavily on alerting users through email. I was wondering if it's a better choice to sign up to googles businesss gmail account.

Would this give me a better result from preventing my emails from being bounced ? 
or should I not bother and go down the traditional path and setup a mail server on my box?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Mail server on your own box. That way you control it end to end. Make sure you have your email servers set up properly, don't put trigger words in the emails - like viagara - and have your users whitelist the email address.

Typically if you aren't sending spam, you shouldn't have a problem.

Google are notorious for not having much support when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a dedicated transactional email provider like [SMTP.com,](http://www.smtp.com/) [SendGrid,](http://sendgrid.com/) or [Postmark.](http://postmarkapp.com/) They provide the mailserver, sending API, and take steps to reduce the amount of mail that hits your users' spam folders for you by configuring things like [DKIM](http://www.dkim.org/), [SPF records](http://www.openspf.org/), and unique IP addresses.

When a site depends heavily on emails being delivered, it often pays to use a dedicated third-party service instead of setting up your own mailserver, purely so that you don't spend time trying to fix deliverability and reliability issues that someone else has already solved.